# Is there a way to integrate framer motion into my astro project? successfully rendered the react component but the animation doesnt seem to be working

Tags: javascript

The animate property doesnt seem to be working even though I don't receive any error and the component is being rendered without any problem

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Card1 = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <motion.div
        className="bg-red-400 w-[10px] h-[10px]"
        animate={{ x: 100 }}
      />
      <h1>yo bros</h1>
    </>
  );
}

export default Card1;
```

Answer (score 8):

just make sure you add the client:load attribute onto your react component when you are adding it into your astro page. Just remember, by default, Astro won't load your JS code.

```
  <Header client:load />
```

That may be your issue.

Comment: To add to that:
The concept is called [hydration](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/framework-components/#hydrating-interactive-components) and is relevant because of the ["islands" principle](https://docs.astro.build/en/concepts/islands/) that Astro follows